# Invariant subspaces in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Can someone please help me to answer the following problem?

> Let $(e_k)$ be a total orthonormal sequence in a separable Hilbert space $H$ and let $T: H \to H$ be defined at $e_k$ by: $T(e_k) = e_{k+1} , k = 1, 2, \dots$ and then linearly and continuously extended to $H$.
>   Find invariant subspaces, with justification.

This is my answer: $X_n=\operatorname{span}\{e_n,e_{n+1},\dots\}$ are invariant subspaces.  But I don't know
how to prove that they are the only invariant subspaces.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe it will help to observe that $X$ is invariant for $T$ iff $X^\perp$ is invariant for $T^*$, which is the right shift operator $T^*(e_k) = e_{k-1}$.

Comment: how it will help ?

Comment: I don't know.  That's why I said "maybe".

Comment: and do you think that the answer of Urban PENDU can be correct?

Comment: As you can see from my comment on Urban's answer, I do not understand why his claim is true, so I don't consider it to be a proof as it stands.

Comment: Do not try to blank out your post.

Comment: Please do not change your question after it has received answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your Operator is actually the unilateral forward shift Operator on the Hardy Space-$H^2(\mathbb{D})$. So By Beurling's Theorem all invariant subspace are given by $X = \phi H^2(\mathbb{D})$, where $\phi$ is an inner function.  In detail See the follwing:

Your Operator is unitarily equivalent to the unilateral forward shift Operator on the Hardy Space-$H^2(\mathbb{D})$. If we define

$U: H^2(\mathbb{D})\rightarrow H$  by $U(z^n) = e_{n+1}$, for all $n \geq 0$

and extend it Linearly. Then $U$ is unitary operator intertwining $T$ and the forward shift operator $M_z$ on $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ i.e. $TU = UM_z$. Now  By Beurling's Theorem all invariant subspace $W$ for $M_z$ are given by $W = \phi H^2(\mathbb{D})$, where $\phi$ is an inner function. And hence all invariant subspace for $T$ is given by $U(W)$.